# 500 error with datatables editor with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor, yajra-datatable

I have setup datatables with editor from yajra/laravel-datatables-editor package.  I can get it where the datatable comes up and works but when i try to edit a field it does not update and I get a 500 error on the ajax call with this message "Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\DataTables\DioceseDataTablesEditor::editRules() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given"

I followed the user tutorial that is given with the package just using a different table with different rows.  Looking for some help as I am stumped to what I am missing.

Here is my DioceseDataTablesEditor.php file which is where the error occurs.

```
namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Diocese;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesEditor;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DioceseDataTablesEditor extends DataTablesEditor
{
    protected $model = Diocese::class;

    /**
     * Get create action validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function createRules()
    {
        return [
            //'diocese' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get edit action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function editRules(Model $model) //This is where the error occurs
    {
        return [
           // 'diocese'  => 'sometimes|required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get remove action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function removeRules(Model $model)
    {
        return [];
    }

        /**
    * Pre-update action event hook.
    *
    * @param Model $model
    * @return array
    */
    public function updating(Model $model, array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

The thing I notice is in the ajax call it never send the unique id of the row which is a column called link which I have set in the Diocese model.  This is what I think may be the issue.  It only sends over the following to fields in the post.

action:edit
data[link][denominat]:Other 
//it is the actual word link and not the link value with a an integer.

Here is my javascript for it.

```
$(function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    }
                });

                var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
                    ajax: "/admin/diocese",
                    table: "#diocese",
                    display: "bootstrap",
                    fields: [
                        { label: 'link', name: 'link' },
                        { label: 'denominat', name: 'denominat', type: 'select', options: [
                            "Catholic", "Episcopal", "Methodist", "PNCC", "American Baptist", "ELCA", "AMEZC", "Presbyterian", "Individual", "Other", "AME Church", "ACNA"
                        ] },
                        { label: 'abbrev', name: 'abbrev' },
                        { label: 'diocese', name: 'diocese' },
                        { label: 'addrone', name: 'addrone' },
                        { label: 'addrtwo', name: 'addrtwo' },
                        { label: 'city', name: 'city' },
                        { label: 'state', name: 'state' },
                        { label: 'zipcode', name: 'zipcode' },
                        { label: 'telephone', name: 'telephone' },
                    ]
                });

                $('#diocese').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
                    editor.inline(this);
                });

                {{$dataTable->generateScripts()}}
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit.  Here is controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\DioceseDataTable;
use App\DataTables\DioceseDataTablesEditor;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class DioceseController extends Controller
{
    public function index(DioceseDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('admin.diocese.index');
    }

    public function store(DioceseDataTablesEditor $editor)
    {
        return $editor->process(request());

    }

    public function getTableColumns($table)
    {
        return Schema::getColumnListing($table);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code, for `"/admin/diocese"` route

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this and will leave the answer for future reference.  Thinking the data being sent as data[link][denominat] = "Others" was wrong I setup a simple test form the send in that data as an ajax post but have it look how I thought it should look which would be data[42456][denominat] = "Others" and when I did that it worked just fine.

So then I looked more at the editor docs and I had to let the editor know the name of my primary key which was "link"  So the changed by code to what is below.

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
                    ajax: "/admin/diocese",
                    table: "#diocese",
                    idSrc: "link",  // ##added this line 
                    display: "bootstrap",
                    fields: [
                        { label: 'link', name: 'link' },
                        { label: 'denominat', name: 'denominat', type: 'select', options: [
                            "Catholic", "Episcopal", "Methodist", "PNCC", "American Baptist", "ELCA", "AMEZC", "Presbyterian", "Individual", "Other", "AME Church", "ACNA"
                        ] },
                        { label: 'abbrev', name: 'abbrev' },
                        { label: 'diocese', name: 'diocese' },
                        { label: 'addrone', name: 'addrone' },
                        { label: 'addrtwo', name: 'addrtwo' },
                        { label: 'city', name: 'city' },
                        { label: 'state', name: 'state' },
                        { label: 'zipcode', name: 'zipcode' },
                        { label: 'telephone', name: 'telephone' },
                    ]
                });
```